# DismissViewController dismissing two UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

I´m presenting a view this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ContractDetailsViewController *contractDetailsViewController = [[ContractDetailsViewController alloc] init];
    contractDetailsViewController.client = self.client;
    contractDetailsViewController.contractId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    [self presentViewController:[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:contractDetailsViewController] animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

After the view appears i dismiss it with:

```
- (void)close
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

The bug is that the view disappears, the view that was behind it also disappears right after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could explain what is happening to your view controllers:

> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated%3acompletion%3a))

This means that if you present view controller A, then view controller B, then call dismiss on view controller B, both view controllers are dismissed (although only B with an animation).

If you want to manage two different hierarchies of view controllers, you could use a second navigation controller. That means, e.g., that you would present a new navigation controller instead of view controller A, and make view controller A the navigation controller's root controller. Then you would push/pop any other required view controller (B, etc.)

Comment: That's right. I used a UINavigationController to get around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per apple documentation.

> If you present several view controllers in succession, and thus build
>   a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view
>   controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.
>   When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated
>   fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the
>   stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition
>   style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers
>   lower in the stack.

If you want to achieve that functionality, just add `UIViews` in current view and show them in modal way. You can remove them one by one.